# Doctrine db connection issues

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Trying to connect to a dababase which is in a different server:

Command line

```
php symfony configure:database "mysql:host=<IP>;dbname=<db_name>" <username> <password>
```

Databases.yml

```
  all:   
    doctrine:     
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase     
      param:       
      dsn: 'mysql:host=<IP>;dbname=<db_name>'
      username: <username>       
      password: <password>
```

Getting error:

> PDO Connection Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: Have you tried, from command line, to connect to that server? To me it sounds more like a problem on the sql server side.

Comment: Yes, tried from command line.. Tried connecting to two different server, same error.. Is there any config that needs to be changed in the server to allow remote access ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant access to the user *from that host*. Something like

`GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';`

More [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

Comment: Thanks, that worked for one of the server. However, the other server still returns the same error after granting access. Could this be due to firewall settings on the server ?

Comment: Is the server set up to listen on the IP you are connecting to? Either this or some firewall...

Comment: Firewall seems to be ok, i checked with the network admin. We are able to PING to the server from our IP.  Kindly let me know how exactly to check if the server is listening to the IP we are connecting.

Comment: look for `bind-address` in you cnf file. Should be the same IP like the one you are connecting to. Also look for `skip-networking` .Should be commented out (or not present). Have a look here for more details information: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: Apologies for making this a bit long. This is my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

```
Apologies for making this a bit long. 
This is the server my.cnf                                                           

[mysqld]
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used (fedora >= 15).
# If you need to run mysqld under different user or group, 
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
user=mysql

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Semisynchronous Replication
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-semisync.html
# uncomment next line on MASTER
;plugin-load=rpl_semi_sync_master=semisync_master.so
# uncomment next line on SLAVE
;plugin-load=rpl_semi_sync_slave=semisync_slave.so

# Others options for Semisynchronous Replication
;rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled=1
;rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout=10
;rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled=1

# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html
;performance_schema


[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```